# How to get data of particular sender and receiver in chatbox?

Tags: django, angular

I want to get all messages history of particular sender and receiver. i am using fronEnd angular5 and Backend Django..

my db sample table :

```
    {            
        "id": 288,
        "name": "Faric",
        "receiver": "drit",
        "text": "hiee",
        "myDate": "2018-07-26T04:38:05.505000Z"
    }
```

chatService:

```
url : string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/msg/';
messages: Subject<ChatMessage>;

  getMessage(): Promise<chatMessage[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json()).topromise(); #url of messages API
  }
```

chatcomponent:

```
 this.chat.getMessage()
 .then(msg=> this.messages = msg); # messges = []
```

using this service and component i get all mssages.. jst i want to get perticular sender and receiver's data. how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ES6's` `find` function to fetch data for a particular sender / receiver,

Let's say if you want to get the data based on the ID field (in your json), you can try something like,

```
this.messageForAnUser = this.messages.find(message=> message.id === THE_SENDER_OR_RECEIVER_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_SEARCH)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but how to call service in this

Comment: if i use this **this.chatservice.getMessage().find(messages=> messages.name === this.name)** then get error :Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.

Comment: Yes, Becuase `getMessage` is typecasted as a promise, hence you are receiving that error.

Comment: yaa.. so what is another way?